# Issue with AutoCompleteTextView in a fragmnet used inside TabbedActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, autocompletetextview, android-tabbed-activity

I have created a TabbedActivity as the main screen for my APP, also i have created a fragment  (used inside the TabbedActivity )to display whenever a particular tab is clicked. 
Inside one of the fragment i am using AutoComplteTextView 
Problem is that the AutoComplteTextView  do not display any suggestions mentioned in the String array list also i am not getting any errors in the log
could any direct to solve this problem
Code 
TabbedActivity  from where the fragment is called

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1){
                View viewMakeTransaction = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_make_transaction, container, false);
                return viewMakeTransaction;
            }
            else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2){
                View viewAddCustomer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_customer, container, false);
                return viewAddCustomer;
            }
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3){
                View viewViewTransaction = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_transaction, container, false);
                return viewViewTransaction;
            }
            else{

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;
            }
        }
```

Fragment (fragment_make_transaction) Code having the AutocompletTextView

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[]{"India","America"};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View viewMakeTransactionFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_make_transaction, container, false);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,COUNTRIES);
    final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) viewMakeTransactionFragment.findViewById(R.id.selectCustomer);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return viewMakeTransactionFragment;
}
```

Steps to recreate the problem 
1. Create a new Android Project - 
Select TabbedActivity and Navigation Style as -ActionBarTabs(with page viewer) as show in the below picture[TabbedActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmneD.png)

2. Click finish - Project will be created
3. Create a new blank Fragment
4. Edit the code from the fragment as below 
   fragment code as of now

   package demo.com.problem;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;

   public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // Inflate the layout for this fragment
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
       }
   }
5. go to TabbedActivity - java code inside the method (onCreateView) 
   call the fragment using the below code

this will call the fragment when the user is on the first screen of the tabbed activity

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1){
        View viewMakeTransaction = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        return viewMakeTransaction;
    }
    else{

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Run the app once to make sure the fragment is getting displayed under section 1

Steps to Add AutoCompleteTextView to the fragment

1. XML file for the fragment

   ```
   <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

   <AutoCompleteTextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
2. Java code for the fragment

   package demo.com.problem;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

   public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
       AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
       private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[]{"India","Aus"};

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,COUNTRIES);
       autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
       autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       return view;
   }
   ```

   }

Issues with the AutoComplete text view [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m78Y9.png)

Comment: Usually a fragment only has one possible layout. You should create fragments for each of your layouts rather than using a flag to determine which layout to inflate.

Comment: As for your question, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Code-Apprentice update the details

Comment: Please read the link I gave.

Comment: i have mentioned all the steps necessary to replicate the issue

Comment: Please fix your code formatting. Each line should have four extra spaces in addition to the desired indentation. You can do this quickly by pasting your code, highlighting it, then pressing Ctrl-K.

Comment: some how its not working for only the code specified in step 4 .. its working for the other code section

Comment: For code inside a list you must add 8 spaces before each line. Indent 4 because of the list and 4 for the code.